# How to load custom application-xxx.yml file out of other application-xxx.yml in spring boot without using profile annotation solution

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to load single **application-xxx.yml** for production environment out of three **application-xxx.yml** and that is decided by the value of environment variable (in my case its) **country**.

**Explanation:**

I have my spring boot microservice (REST api) deployed in different aws regions for different countries.

I have added 3 different yml/properties files under resource folder such as:

**For USA > application-usa.yml.**

**For Germany >  application-ger.yml .**

**For India > application-ind.yml .**

(All three yml files contains similar properties but different values for them)

So lets say, if env. variable **country == USA** then **application-usa.yml** file should be loaded but not rest of the mentioned application-xxx.yaml files 
and so on .....

So in the end , only one yaml file out of above 3, should get loaded depending on value for env variable  **country**

So how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using gradle build tool. You have to create three directories like usa, germany and india in the resources directory and keep those yml files under each directory. In the application build time you have to copy the specific yml file to resources directory from the country(usa, germany or india) directory. To identify the specific country in the build time, you have to pass the country name as parameter as below:

```
./gradlew my-project:bootRun -Pcountry=india
```

Below is a sample gradle code to copy specific yml file from country directory to resources directory:

```
def country = project.property('country') //Get the country name

//Copy yml files from country directory to resources directory.
//You have to replace file_path with your projects file path.
task copyYmlFile(type: Copy) {   
    from "file_path/resources/${country}"
    into "file_path/resources"
}

bootRun {
    dependsOn 'copyYmlFile' //Call the yml copy task in the project build time
    //Rest of the codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring support `spring.profiles.active` property to activate properties when loading the application. You just need to pass the value of this property when running the application in an environment.

**JVM System Parameter**

The profile names can also be passed in via a JVM system parameter. The profile names passed as the parameter will be activated during application start-up:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=usa
```

**Environment Variable**

In a Unix environment, profiles can also be activated via the environment variable:

```
export spring_profiles_active=usa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the application.properties file according to an environment variable or -D compilation flag.

From the Spring Documentation:

> If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file
>   name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a
>   spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an
>   explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment
>   property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or
>   file paths). The following example shows how to specify a different
>   file name:

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject
```

> The following example shows how to specify two locations:

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

For this, and some other options of how to change externalized configuration, take a look here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config